# Access reports based on sorted query?

Tags: ms-access

When creating an Access report based on a query, when the report needs to be sorted, one has to define the sort keys and order in the report itself, using the sorting and grouping icon.
My question is whether defining any sort order in the underlying query has impact interms of performance, or are these just ignored by Access report ?

Answer (score 0):

For extremely large result sets the extra sort on the query *might* slow things down, so it would be best to avoid it if you can. I have not seen any mention of an Access report "ignoring" an ORDER BY clause on the underlying query. I suppose it's *possible*, but I sort of doubt it....